# How do I get rid of the MultiValueDictKey error while doing an AJAX get request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

There are multiple divs on a page and each div has a form. I want to do an AJAX Get so that the text entered into a form and the id of the div in which the form was contained is passed onto a Django view, saved into the database there and then the text shown in a similar div at the bottom of the page. I wrote the following code:

HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="post #{{post.id}}"><h3>{{post.post}}</h3>
<input type = "text" style="display:none;">{% csrf_token %}</input>
<button type="button" class="btn-primary" id='{{post.id}}'>Add post.</button>
</form>
</div>
```

scripts.js

```
$(".btn-primary").click(function(){
            var post_id = $(this).attr('id');
            var post_text = $(this).parent().children("input").val();
                $.get('/makepost/'),{post_id:post_id, post_text:post_text }, function(data){
                    newsimp_id = "#"+data;
                    $.scrollTo($(newsimp_id).position().top, 500);
                }
            });
```

django view

```
def makepost(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    parent_post_id = int(request.GET['post_id'])
    post_text = request.GET['post_text']
    parent_post = Post.objects.get(id=parent_post_id)
    c = Post.objects.get_or_create(post = parent_post.post, parent_post = parent_post_id,  post = post_text, coeficient = parent_post.coeficient + 1)[0]
    new_post_id = c.id
    return HttpResponse(new_post_id)
```

This throws the following error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /makepost/
"'post_id'"
```

post.post signifies the post field in the model called post.

What do I do? What does this error mean? Is there an alternative?

Comment: You need to show more details of the error. You're not using a key "simpler_id" anywhere in the code you've posted: you should show the actual code and the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry. That was the error from another page. Posted mistakenly. Edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks. It was a syntax error. I had missed parens for the $.get function's parameters. The correct code:

scripts.js

```
$(".btn-primary").click(function(){
            var post_id = $(this).attr('id');
            var post_text = $(this).parent().children("input").val();
                $.get(('/makepost/'),{post_id:post_id, post_text:post_text }, function(data){
                    newsimp_id = "#"+data;
                    $.scrollTo($(newsimp_id).position().top, 500);
                });
            });
```